# Trouble getting a button that's part of the background to work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble creating the following concept. I want a specific part of the website's image that's mapped to link to another page in the site, and I want the whole image to stretch to the width of the viewer. I have both of these, but when the image stretches it throws off the mapping. Is there a way to have it automatically compensate?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        #bg { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; }
        .bgwidth { width: 100%; }
        .bgheight { height: 100%; }

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {   

        var theWindow        = $(window),
            $bg              = $("#bg"),
            aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

        function resizeBg() {

            if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                $bg
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgheight');
            } else {
                $bg
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgwidth');
            }

        }

        theWindow.resize(function() {
            resizeBg();
        }).trigger("resize");

    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="background.png" id="bg" usemap = #bgmap alt="">
<map name=bgmap>
<area shape=Rect Coords=410,200,595,390 Href="http://www.example.com"> 
</map> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors in your code

```
<body>
    <img src="background.png" id="bg" usemap="#bgmap" alt="">
<map name="bgmap">
<area shape="Rect" Coords="410,200,595,390" href="http://www.example.com"> 
</map> 

</body>
```